# White Point Correction in ColorConvert

Tags: color

One can do color space transformation with Mathematica's ColorConvert function. This function supports basically all relevant color spaces. However there is one not well documented statement in this function about the chromatic (white point) adaption of transformations which reads

*ColorConvert automatically performs chromatic (white point) adaptation. D50 white point is assumed   for "XYZ", "LAB", "LUV", and "LCH" and D65 for "RGB", "CMYK", "HSB", and "Grayscale".*

however there is no clear indication if one could modify this default behaviour by specifying another illuminant than D50 or D60 (e.g. A or C) for color transformations. The option *WhitePoint* which is available e.g. for Chromaticity plot is not working with ColorConvert.

A concrete example would be the transformation from L*u*v* color space coordinates {70, -60, 80} to XYZ color space which would be the command

`ColorConvert[{70,-60,80}/100,"LUV","XYZ"]`

which yields the result XYZColor[{0.227989,0.407494,0.008952}] for the D50 illuminant but if one would like to use illuminant e.g. "C" the correct result should be XYZColor[{0.225472,0.407494,0.114944}].

Any info on potentially hidden options are welcome...

Comment: This is a known shortcoming of the conversion framework and something I would like to add a certain point. The the effort is not insignificant though, so I won't hold my breath. PS: why do you think is not well documented? any suggestion on how to make it clearer? thanks

Comment: I think the architecture of the conversion environment is somehow problematic. The Color spaces have different white points for different illuminants and thus the illuminant should be part of the specification of the color space. Currently the illuminant seems to be hardcoded, so this should be mentioned in the documentation along the info which illuminants are the standard settings....